# Javascript all words are 3 characters or longer

Tags: javascript

Let say I have a `string = 'all these words are three characters orr longer'`

I want to check it

```
if (string.someWayToCheckAllWordsAre3CharactersOrLonger) {
  alert("it's valid!");
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`every`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Before you can use `every` the string need to be pre-processed.

1. `trim` the string, remove the leading and trailing spaces.
2. `split` the string by one or more space characters
3. Then use `every` to check if length every element of the array is greater than or equal to three.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a9cyjjut/)

```
var string = 'all these words are three characters orr longer';
string.trim().split(/\s+/).every(function(e) { return e.length >= 3; });
```

Answer (score 4):

Split the string into an array, then check if each word is longer than 3 characters using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
var string = 'all these words are three characters orr longer';

// Using regex \s+ to split the string, so only words are get in the array
string.trim().split(/\s+/).every(e => e.length >= 3);
```

Comment: ES2015 specific, but nice :)

Comment: I do, in Node code (using Node 4, now).  I just wouldn't put it in browser code just yet :)

Comment: You can use `\s+` to split the string

Comment: @Tushar There's no need for regex here.

Comment: Just for the record, I would recommend trimming before splitting, just in case.

Comment: @BenFortune `> ' a   b'.split(' ');
[ '', 'a', '', '', 'b' ]` in this case every will return `false`. Note there are two spaces between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this

```
var string = "all these words are three characters orr longer";
var words = string.split(' ');

var allWordsAreLongerThanThreeChars = true;
for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    if(words[i].length < 3){
        allWordsAreLongerThanThreeChars = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple steps: split string into an array using `.split()`, loop through the array and check the length of each word using `.length()`. Hope this helps.

```
var string = 'all these words are three characters orr longer';
var stringArray = string.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){ 
  if(stringArray[i].length >= 3) { 
    alert(stringArray[i]);
   }
};
```